# How to get source maps working in Angular 4 and Laravel 5.6 (.map files are missing after build)

Tags: angular, laravel-5, source-maps

I inherited a Laravel and Angular app, and I am trying come up to speed.

I run a shell script which basically compiles everything into the project's `./public` folder and `nginx` serves the app from there.

Here is the script that builds everything:

> ./compile-js.sh

```
rm -rf ./public/*.{js,css,svg,woff2,ttf,woff,eot,map,json,html,txt}* ./public/fonts ./public/images ./angular-app/dist/
cd ./angular-app/
yarn install
yarn run build:dev
rm -f ./dist/*.{txt,map} #{txt,map}
cd ../
cp -r ./angular-app/dist/* ./public/

cssTemplate=./resources/views/angular/angular-css.blade.php
jsTemplate=./resources/views/angular/angular-js.blade.php

beginJs='<script type="text/javascript" src="'
endJs='"></script>'

beginInlineJs='<script type="text/javascript">'
endInlineJs='</script>'

beginStyle='<link rel="stylesheet" href="'
endStyle='"/>'

truncate -s 0 "$jsTemplate"
truncate -s 0 "$cssTemplate"

src="$(cat ./public/inlin*.bundle.js)"
echo "$beginInlineJs$src$endInlineJs" >> "$jsTemplate"

src="$(find ./public/ -name 'script*.bundle.js' -type f -exec basename {} \;)"
echo "$beginJs$src$endJs" >> "$jsTemplate"

src="$(cat ./public/sw-registe*.bundle.js)"
echo "$beginInlineJs$src$endInlineJs" >> "$jsTemplate"

src="$(find ./public/ -name 'polyfill*.bundle.js' -type f -exec basename {} \;)"
echo "$beginJs$src$endJs" >> "$jsTemplate"

src="$(find ./public/ -name 'vendo*.bundle.js' -type f -exec basename {} \;)"
echo "$beginJs$src$endJs" >> "$jsTemplate"

src="$(find ./public/ -name 'mai*.bundle.js' -type f -exec basename {} \;)"
echo "$beginJs$src$endJs" >> "$jsTemplate"

src="$(find ./public/ -name 'style*.bundle.css' -type f -exec basename {} \;)"
echo "$beginStyle$src$endStyle" >> "$cssTemplate"
```

Here are the scripts:

> ./angular-app/package.json

```
"build": "ng build --env=prod --prod --aot --output-path ./dist",
"build:dev": "ng build --sourcemap=true --extract-css --env=dev --output-path ./dist",
```

I just changed the shell script today to `yarn run build:dev` (it was previously running in prod mode, making debugging very hard). Now after, Chrome Dev Tools is reporting that source maps are detected, but I am also seeing in the console:

```
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://1.bundle.js.map
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://2.bundle.js.map
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://3.chunk.js.map
```

I see there are no `.map` files in the `./public` folder, so this is probably why I am seeing this.

Where should I look to make Webpack create the map files?

- my `tsconfig.json` file has `"sourceMap": true,`
- there is no `webpack://` area in the Dev Tools Sources Tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. The reason is in the shown `./compile-js.sh` file.

This is the culprit here:

```
rm -f ./dist/*.{txt,map} #{txt,map}
```

It was creating the map files and then deleting them before copying everything to `./public`.

Changed it to this and it fixed it:

```
rm -f ./dist/*.{txt} #{txt}
```

I'm using this dev script now also:

```
"build:dev": "ng build --source-map --aot --extract-css --env=dev --output-path ./dist",
```

Rather than delete this question, I will keep it because searching Google for information about this stuff was pretty terrible. Maybe it will help someone one day.